# reformat values in a table

Tags: sed, tr, table

I have some tables, in which I need to replace several values. I have different commands `sed` and `tr` that work just fine when I apply them to a single file.
But somehow, when I want to build a loop from this commands it is not working at all. Here is my loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
in_dir=/home/stevens/SUMARIO/regional_model/data/basin
stations="almourol alton cuntan eldeim farakka koulikoro lobith louth olivenca stolb tangnaihai"
gcms="gfdl-esm2m hadgem2-es ipsl-cm5a-lr miroc-esm-chem noresm1-m"
scenarios="rcp8p5"

for station in ${stations};do
  echo "go to directory"
  cd ${in_dir}/${station}
  for gcm in ${gcms};do
    for rcp in ${rcps};do
      cd ${in_dir}/${station}
      echo "replace datum"
      sed 's/"datum"/"YEAR-MONTH-DAY"/g' ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario} > ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.c
      echo "delete hour"
      sed 's/ 12:00:00//g' ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.c > ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.cs
      echo "replace - to ;"
      tr "-" ";" < ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.cs > ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.csv
      rm ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.cs ${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}.c
    done
  done
done
```

Does anyone has an idea why this loop doesn´t work.

Comment: try putting `set -x` or perhaps `set -u` to the front of the script to see what it actually does when you run it.

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined `${rcps}` nor `${scenario}`

Comment: You may find www.shellcheck.net helpful

Comment: @steeldriver - Thank you for the shellcheck tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you haven't defined the `rcps` variable
2. you defined `scenarios` but used `scenario`

Here's a version of your script that fixes those problems and makes a few other improvements:

- formatted with extra newlines and aligned indentation to improve readability
- use arrays rather than space-separated strings
- use `sed` once rather than multiple times plus `tr`
- double-quotes all the variables
- single-quotes all fixed strings
- defines a variable (`$fname`) to hold the constructed filename (`${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}`) rather than re-constructing it every time you use it, which is both much harder to read AND very prone to typing errors.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

in_dir='/home/stevens/SUMARIO/regional_model/data/basin'

stations=(almourol alton cuntan eldeim farakka koulikoro lobith louth
          olivenca stolb tangnaihai)

gcms=(gfdl-esm2m hadgem2-es ipsl-cm5a-lr miroc-esm-chem noresm1-m)

scenario='rcp8p5'

rcps=(a b c)

for station in "${stations[@]}" ; do
  cd "${in_dir}/${station}"

  for gcm in "${gcms[@]}"; do
    for rcp in "${rcps[@]}" ; do

      fname="${station}_${gcm}_${scenario}"
      echo "replace datum: $fname"

      sed -e 's/"datum"/"YEAR-MONTH-DAY"/g;
              s/ 12:00:00//g;
              s/-/;/g' "$fname" > "${fname}.csv"
    done
  done
done
```

If you want to replace the string `"datum"` with an actual date, you'd have to do something like:

1. define `YMD=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` along with the other vars and arrays
2. and rewrite the `sed` script as this:

```bash
      sed -e 's/"datum"/"'"${YMD}"'"/g;
              s/ 12:00:00//g;
              s/-/;/g' "$fname" > "${fname}.csv"
```

BTW, if you really did mean to have multiple scenarios, you'll have to define `scenarios` as another array and add another loop `for scenario in "${scenarios[@]}" ; do ..... done`